# stylus add ../ in front of url('#svgPath')

Tags: stylus, gulp-stylus

This is really weird.

stylus compile :
`clip-path url(#expHead-clip-path)`

into :   `clip-path = url(../#expHead-clip-path);`

Any idea why ?
this is my gulpfile for stylus :

```
gulp.task('stylus', function () {
    var comp = (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') ? false : true;
    gutil.log('stylus config.env : ' + process.env.NODE_ENV+'  comp = '+comp);
    gulp.src(config.src)
    .pipe(stylus({
        compress: comp
    }))
    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(autoprefixer().on('error', handleErrors))
    .pipe(concatCss('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulpif(comp, minifyCSS()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Maybe add more contextual code, especially the relevant part of your gulp file?

Comment: What are `config.src` and `config.dest ` set to? Is one the parent directory of the other?

Comment: @edemaine damned. I didn't think about that. You're right, dest is '/'  src is '/core/css/**/*.styl'. It must be the reason. You think I can fixe it without changing my architecture ?

Comment: It seems like a bug in Stylus or one of the two layers in between you and Stylus: [gulp-stylus](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-stylus) or [accord/stylus](https://github.com/jenius/accord/blob/master/docs/stylus.md). Maybe open an issue on ... gulp-stylus?